# Why is there a difference between the output of a Script and a Terminal Command?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

Why does bash change the output of my script in comparison to the terminal output?

If I type

```
dig +noall +answer NS google.com
```

[I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmvW0.png)

But if I do it with a script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Domain: "
read DOMAIN
echo
DIG=$(dig +noall +answer NS $DOMAIN)
echo $DIG
```

I get
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAU9H.png)

I want to have the same results as if I typed the command in the console.

I know I could just save and sort (not exactly sort but awk) them in a file but if possible I want to get the same result without having to save the results in a file.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 if that helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quote your variables!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/102168)

```
$ DIG=$(dig +noall +answer NS google.com)

$ echo $DIG
google.com. 86308 IN NS ns2.google.com. google.com. 86308 IN NS ns3.google.com. google.com. 86308 IN NS ns1.google.com. google.com. 86308 IN NS ns4.google.com.

$ echo "$DIG"
google.com.             86295   IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             86295   IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             86295   IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
google.com.             86295   IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
```